# Prove that a linear mapping $ L : \mathbb{R^m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ is one-to-one iff $Ker(L) = \vec{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations

Prove that a linear mapping $ L  : \mathbb{R^m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}  $       is one-to-one *if and only if* $Ker(L) = \vec{0}$.

Can someone breakdown the step by step process of solving this proof?

Comment: You've chosen a very descriptive title and formatted your question nicely, especially for a new user. Welcome to Math.SE, and I hope you find the community helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $L$ is not one-to-one. Then there are some $x,y$ with $x \neq y$ such that $L(x) = L(y)$. By linearity, this means that $L(x-y) = 0$, so that $x-y$ is in the kernel of $L$. Thus if $L$ is not one-to-one, then $L$ has nontrivial kernel. This is equivalent to its contrapositive, which is that if $L$ has trivial kernel, then $L$ is one-to-one.

On the other hand, suppose that the kernel of $L$ is nontrivial. Then in particular, there is some $x \neq 0$ such that $L(x) = 0$. But then $L(x) = L(0) = 0$, so that $L$ is not one-to-one.

This completes the proof. $\diamondsuit$